# This is an inductor symbol, right?

Tags: pcb, relay, inductor

This is from the PCB in a microwave oven. On the right side, there are two symbols with the labels DU and OMIF. They look like inductors. Is that correct?

sidenote: this is found underneath a relay, the DU1PU. I have removed the relay. I'm guessing the components are connected to the relay pins.

[image]

Comment: What does the repair manual say?

Comment: No manual found. The microwave is from 1997, and I picked it up used at a yard sale.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I suspect that those symbols represent the relay coil.

The board is apparently designed to use either of two types of relay - the DU1PU that you have, and an OMIF, which is slightly larger, and has the coil terminals farther from the contact terminals

Comment: [Here's a sample Tyco OMIF datasheet](http://datasheet.octopart.com/OMIF-S-124LM,300-Tyco-Electronics-datasheet-12510610.pdf). The (shortest) distance from a coil pin to the corresponding switch pin (on the same side) is 20.0mm. As for the DU1PU... [finding a datasheet for it is bit of a challenge](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/146125/datasheet-for-a-du1pu-relay).

Comment: I believe too. They should be representing a relay coil.