# Datasheet for a DU1PU relay?

Tags: arduino, relay, datasheet, pinout

I took apart an old microwave oven and found the relay the computer chip closes to activate the magnetron. The relay is a DEC DU1PU, made in China. Does anyone have a datasheet for it? I'm mostly looking for the pin-out. I'm wishing to control the relay with an Arduino, if possible.

[image]

Comment: Well looking at the info in the relay its a 12V DC coil switching up to 16A at 250V AC. You should be able to work out the pin connections with nothing more than a simple continuity. tester

Comment: you might also find this useful http://www.wikihow.com/Test-a-Relay

Comment: Most would choose a 5v-coil relay for arduino use, though you should be able to drive that with some care, a 12v supply, an NPN transistor, catch diode, and a base resistor.

Answer (score 2):

Almost certainly very similar to [this one](http://www.hongfa.com/pro/pdf/HF25F_en.pdf) (except for the contact rating).

[image]

Note that the contacts are present on the quick connects (top of the relay) but one is also brought down to the PCB. If you're switching mains voltage be sure to stay well clear of that one.

**Be sure** to double-check this pinout with a multimeter **before** depending on it. The two pins on the end (the coil) should measure a few hundred ohms, and then contacts should not show continuity (even on high resistance range) to the coil connections.

Edit: Based on the Japanese datasheet @Respawned found, I'd say the bottom non-coil terminal may not, in fact, be connected to one of the contacts- it appears to show it connected to another support terminal and nothing else, but your relay only appears to have one pin in that area, so it's important to check with a multimeter.

Answer (score 2):

The Japanese DEC (Daiichi Electric Co.) appears to be http://www.j-dec.co.jp/ but its web site is in Japanese only... despite having an "English" link at the top (which does nothing for me, in Google Chrome anyway). They do have a datasheet for their DU series (which includes the DU1PU) at http://www.j-dec.co.jp/images/pdf/du.pdf but it's in Japanese only!

This DEC is a fairly small company (200 employees) albeit founded in 1957. They have a factory in China (Hangzhou) since 1993 [which explains the marking on your sample], and also a new factory in Thailand since 2010.

The two large and flat connectors on the top are clearly the switch side and the small ones diagonally located opposite to the large ones on the bottom are clearly the coil. But it seem that your device has a missing pin or there was a design change, because the datasheet shows two variants DU1PU(1P) and DU1PU(1PR) both of which seem to have 4 pins on the bottom; the extra pins are probably for mechanical stability. It's not clear to me from the diagram if the non-coil pins on the bottom are connected to anything, so you should check with an ohmmeter for continuity.[image]

Comment: Good find, and worth a +1 just for the leg lamp.